# CSS: How to make div background width fit

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this question is duplicated, I cannot find one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      html, body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      body {

      }
      .image {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/svvK5z4/about-background.jpg');
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make this background's width fit perfectly  to the screen and adjust the height to the ratio(This image's height is way longer than width, therefore horizontal scrollbar will appear.)
and when I decrease the width of the browser, It just cut itself so I don't have to see the vertical scroll bar. All I want to see is horizontal scroll bar.

Sorry for the bad explanation. I will respond as fast as I can if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. The image you are using:
https://i.ibb.co/svvK5z4/about-background.jpg
is squared (it has the same height and width) and so it won't fit to a rectangular screen without stretching it or repeating it.

Comment: That's strange.. I uploaded the image to Img.bb and I think something went wrong. Image link is here : https://imgur.com/a/612Dfln

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by seeing the horizontal sidebar in full screen? if you want the image to always be the width of your screen, how could you have an horizontal sidebar?

Comment: Since width of the image is shorter than height of the image, when I use fullscreen, horizontal bar will appear to show the rest of image

Comment: I think you mean vertical bar, check my answer to see if that's what you want (second script)

Comment: Yeah, that second code was perfect but I want to overlay text on image, that's why I make background on <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
.image {

  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

Of course, make sure to change the URL to your needs. This should also fit the full screen for any browser or screen size. You can read more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry but what I wanted to know was how to make image's width always same as my full screen size, and adjust height to the original ratio so when I use fullscreen, I could see the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry, I think that the image is the problem. With most screens being rectangular in shape, it is hard for a square image to fit 100% on the screen. If you crop the image to you won likeness, that might work. Just a thought...




**Edit: I just noticed your latest post on the question. The image seems to not square in shape. Therefore, I think taking out the `height: 100%;` and just leaving `width: 100%;` might work, as it will automatically generate the height, based on the width**

Comment: I found that the link of image is broken, Image link is here : imgur.com/a/612Dfln

Comment: Yep, that was the image I tried to refer to in the edit. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I cannot even understand my question fully, It is like messed up in my head... anyways, thanks for your help, I will try to use that code

Answer (score 1):

You image is not the right shape so it will look deformed in a rectangular screen. I cut it to be rectangular. Is this what you want?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/9hXcf0G.jpg');
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue sed nibh vel pulvinar. Praesent nisl tellus, vestibulum ut metus sed, auctor elementum urna. Phasellus ullamcorper augue luctus orci rutrum, non finibus velit faucibus. Aliquam vel tortor
    interdum, gravida lacus quis, sollicitudin ligula. Maecenas sed nulla in nulla gravida iaculis pellentesque non neque. Quisque interdum pretium tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc non cursus justo, et vehicula ligula. Fusce imperdiet maximus fermentum.
    Curabitur eget ultricies leo. Nulla facilisi. Integer arcu dui, sagittis fermentum orci et, sollicitudin iaculis enim. Mauris diam augue, condimentum vitae gravida ac, fringilla sed ipsum.
  </p>

  <p>Aenean ut ultrices orci, id iaculis ante. Pellentesque aliquet nulla vitae accumsan interdum. Integer commodo eu tortor eu tempus. Suspendisse quis leo non tortor auctor accumsan sit amet id justo. Integer eget vulputate diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum efficitur consequat convallis. Aenean ac orci justo. Nam non mi ornare, accumsan odio sed, efficitur risus. Ut gravida vestibulum vestibulum. Nullam eget rutrum arcu, vitae efficitur
    nisi. Aliquam quis ipsum fermentum, varius arcu vitae, interdum neque. Maecenas nec arcu vitae nulla placerat hendrerit. Vestibulum vitae convallis ex.
  </p>



  <p>Sed nec porttitor lacus. Integer quam lectus, volutpat eu quam vitae, efficitur pulvinar libero. Vivamus ut dui eu dui venenatis suscipit ornare quis nunc. Aliquam a dolor eget risus vehicula mollis eu eget ante. Mauris at arcu sed purus cursus laoreet.
    Aliquam efficitur non dui ac semper. Phasellus non interdum arcu. Etiam dolor mauris, elementum sed egestas nec, condimentum sit amet elit. Phasellus laoreet, ligula vel feugiat tempus, neque lorem rhoncus dui, et mollis dui risus ut mi. Phasellus
    accumsan urna eu vehicula lacinia. Cras auctor ipsum ligula, non feugiat turpis molestie at. Mauris varius ex ut vulputate accumsan. Etiam et tristique metus. Nam dignissim sapien vitae ipsum elementum faucibus id ac tortor.</p>


</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, and I want to fix the width static so I can see the full image only when I set the full screen

Comment: and horizontal scroll bar appear because when its ratio is same, height is longer than width so it needs to be extended

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. Do you have any live examples of what you want (from other websites for example)?

Comment: Second code was what I was thought, but last thing is how could I apply the same to <div>'s background? since I want to overlay texts. Thanks
About the example, I will try to find it

Comment: https://workstack.io/features Like this website, It is scrollable and it does not have vertical scroll bar

Comment: The difference is that the image that they are using is wider than taller:
https://workstack.io/img/color-splash.jpg
that's why it works